# Problems starting to use PhoneGap plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, wikitude

I'm new with Wikitude and just trying to set up a PhoneGap project using the Wikitude PhoneGap plugin and it's becoming an impossible task for me! I do follow every single step stated in http://www.wikitude.com/developer/documentation/phonegap but I'm not able to get it work.

Mainly, I do the following:

1. Create a new PhoneGap projetc.
2. Install the Wikitude PhoneGap plugin (by: phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/Wikitude/wikitude-phonegap.git).
3. Modify my index.html just to check if the device is capable of running an Augmented Reality experience, and at this point, when I include this in my index.js (for instance, just inside onDeviceReady function), it doesn't work. It gets stack in the following sentence:

app.wikitudePlugin = cordova.require("com.wikitude.phonegap.WikitudePlugin.WikitudePlugin");

Could you please help me with this?

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Comment: do you have test your code on any device?

Comment: prabhu, thank you very much for your interest. Finally I was able to get the Wikitude PhoneGap plugin working by just building the project with PhoneGap and then moving to Xcode, but I couldn't do it only using the PhoneGap Developer App as I do with other projects. Regards.